# Python mediapipe handdetector error: create_int(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: python, mediapipe, cvzone

HandTracking.py (Main Python File) this is my main Python File where I run the code using VSCODE

I'm just following the Youtube Video from
Murtaza's Workshop - Robotics and AI

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import HandTrackingModule as htm
import time
import autopy

##########################
wCam, hCam = 640, 480
##########################

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)
pTime = 0
detector = htm.handDetector(maxHands=1)

while True:
    # 1. Find Hnd Landmarks
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
    # 2. Get the tip of the index and middle fingers 
    # 3. Check wwhich fingers are up
    # 4. Only Index Finger : Moving Mode
    # 5. Convert Coordinates
    # 6. Smoothen the values for smooth cursor
    # 7. Move the MOUSE CURSOR!
    # 8. Both Index and middle fingers are up : CLICK MODE
    # 9. Find Distance between fingers
    # 10. Click mouse if distance short
    # 11. Frame rate
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2,
        (255, 0, 0), 2)
    # 12. Display

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k==ord('1'):
        break
```

**This is the other python file named "HandTrackingModule.py"**

```
Hand Tracing Module
By: Murtaza Hassan
Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/c/MurtazasWorkshopRoboticsandAI
Website: https://www.computervision.zone/
"""

import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import math
import numpy as np


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, model_complexity=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.tipIds = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        xList = []
        yList = []
        bbox = []
        self.lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                xList.append(cx)
                yList.append(cy)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                self.lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

            xmin, xmax = min(xList), max(xList)
            ymin, ymax = min(yList), max(yList)
            bbox = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

            if draw:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (xmin - 20, ymin - 20), (xmax + 20, ymax + 20),
                              (0, 255, 0), 2)

        return self.lmList, bbox

    def fingersUp(self):
        fingers = []
        # Thumb
        if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)

        # Fingers
        for id in range(1, 5):

            if self.lmList[self.tipIds[id]][2] < self.lmList[self.tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)

        # totalFingers = fingers.count(1)

        return fingers

    def findDistance(self, p1, p2, img, draw=True,r=15, t=3):
        x1, y1 = self.lmList[p1][1:]
        x2, y2 = self.lmList[p2][1:]
        cx, cy = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2

        if draw:
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), t)
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), r, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        length = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

        return length, img, [x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy]


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm just following the code from youtube and it seems that I have this error even though its perfectly working from the video.

**THE ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\Romwald\Desktop\OpenCV Code tutorial\HANDGESTURE\HandTracking.py", line 15, in <module>
    detector = htm.handDetector(maxHands=1)
  File "d:\Users\Romwald\Desktop\OpenCV Code tutorial\HANDGESTURE\HandTrackingModule.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
  File "C:\Users\Romwald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 129, in __init__
    'multi_handedness'
  File "C:\Users\Romwald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 260, in __init__
    for name, data in (side_inputs or {}).items()
  File "C:\Users\Romwald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 260, in <dictcomp>
    for name, data in (side_inputs or {}).items()
  File "C:\Users\Romwald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
[ WARN:0@2.743] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nvm fixed it.
Just did everything here:**

Installed python Python 3.7.4

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install opencv-python

pip install mediapipe or use     or     py -m pip install mediapipe

pip install mediapipe==0.8.8 (for Hands())

pip install autopy

pip install --upgrade virtualenv

pip install tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

You missed some code. Just replace your constructor code with this one:

```
def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, model_complexity=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon        
        self.model_complexity = model_complexity
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(
            self.mode, self.maxHands, self.model_complexity, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
```